# Why do my flag requests are still active?

Tags: discussion, moderators, flagging

Yesterday I flagged two answers( [1st answer](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/5678/why-do-whatsapp-is-not-working-properly-after-upgrading-my-lumia-525-to-windows/8617#8617) & [2nd answer](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/5678/why-do-whatsapp-is-not-working-properly-after-upgrading-my-lumia-525-to-windows/8621#8621) ) as 'Not an Answer' and today I requested Mods to lock [my question](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/5678/why-do-whatsapp-is-not-working-properly-after-upgrading-my-lumia-525-to-windows). All my three flag requests are still active. Mods should accept it or declined it but they are not doing like that. I know Mods are active in this site because I checked their profile page. May I know the reason why they are not responding to my requests? Why these much delay in response?

[My Flag Summary](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/3521)

Screen shot:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

There is a difference between "active" and "handling flags" (I don't believe I was even active in that period, for example).

It's my belief that everyone has their part to play in keeping the site "healthy", and whilst moderators are here to, well, moderate, we all make a difference - a down vote and a comment can be far more powerful to the poster than a moderator weighing in and deleting the post. Like all the Stack Exchange sites, there is [a balance](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/) between reacting to flags, and encouraging/allowing the wider community handling the issue themselves (be it through high reputation users following through the [review](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/review) process (currently available to 8 users with more than [2000 reputation](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)), or simply through commenting and/or downvoting) - if followed through in this manner, the system itself will decide to protect questions as required, as it appears to have in this instance.

This does also highlight an important principle for Stack Exchange sties, and that is we should **all vote to reinforce *good* behaviour**, to help reflect the reputation, and provide a larger group of people that *can* help handle the reviews.

One principle I always try to take on board in all my activity online, is borrowed from Wikipedia, and that is to assume that the post was made in good faith. In the example you've provided, it may be the case that new people don't quite get the idea of Stack Exchange, and they think it works like a traditional message board - a quick, friendly, comment can be a nicer way of handling a new user, rather than the comparatively silent approach of flagging their post.

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99474/130044